# setTextIsSelectable(true) for array

Tags: android

in my android app i want to enable copy and with setTextIsSelectable(true) it works for title but not for list view items .list view items are array.

```
     titleTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

with above code i can copy title but i want to enable text copy from body which is coming from one text file and it is in listview

```
titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleID);
listViewLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ListViewLinearLayout);

titleTextView.setTypeface(font);

dataValues[0] = "";
dataValues[1] = "";

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

jokesList = new ArrayList<>();
timeDateList = new ArrayList<>();

adapter = new SwipeDownListAdapter(this, jokesList, timeDateList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

any idea for achieving goal will be great,. 
 i tried this but it gives error
         jokesList.setTextIsSelectable(true);

it gives error boolean only it says

this is joke listview array

Boy: The principal is so dumb!/-%/Girl: Do you know who I am?/-%/Boy: No.../-%/Girl: I am the principal's daughter!/-%/Boy: Do you know who I am?/-%/Girl: No.../-%/Boy: Good! *walks away*|Friday, 05:23:04pm

---

Boy: *calls 911* Hello? I need your help!/-%/911: Alright, What is it?/-%/Boy: Two girls are fighting over me!/-%/911: So what's your emergency?/-%/Boy: The ugly one is winning.|Friday, 05:36:19pm

---

The closest Iâ€™ve been to a diet this year is erasing food searches from my browser history./-%//-%/Lollzzzzz :p|Friday, 05:44:35pm

---

My friend thinks he is smart. He told me an onion is the only food that makes you cry, so I threw a coconut at his face.|Tuesday, 10:23:41am

---

Comment: `jokesList` is an ArrayList. Why would you think `jokesList.setTextIsSelectable` is a valid method?

Comment: @cricket_007 how to do.plz guide

Comment: `setTextIsSelectable` is only a method for objects of the type `TextView`, that is why it works for `titleTextView`. I have no idea what type of data you have in `jokesList` because you don't have a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 added example

Comment: No, you only added the data, not code for how you defined `jokesList`. Please read that link and make **complete** example

Comment: @cricket_007 with data one can easily identify